# where's the cookie from?

Tags: cookies, httpwebrequest

I've never visited one website before, for the first time I visit this website and try to login, I use fiddler to monitor the post data,

in the http post header, there's already cookie in there. how would that happen?

How can I generate a cookie to auto login the website?

The following is the raw header.

```
POST https://us.battle.net/login/en/?ref=&app= HTTP/1.1
Host: us.battle.net
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 64
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: https://us.battle.net
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko)        Chrome/21.0.1180.77 Safari/537.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: https://us.battle.net/login/en/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.6
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: perm=1; __utma=134253166.2032096419.1344959743.1344959743.1344959743.1; __utmb=134253166.2.10.1344959743; __utmc=134253166; __utmz=134253166.1344959743.1.1.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided)

accountName=aaaa%40me.com&password=password&persistLogin=on
```

Answer (score 0):

The cookie could have been generated on the `GET` request when you visited the login page.

Alternatively, although you haven't directly visited a website, it may have been integrated into another website you have visited, for example in an iframe. This is common with ad networks for example.

Comment: GET http://battle.net/ HTTP/1.1
Host: battle.net
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.77 Safari/537.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.6
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3

Comment: GET http://eu.battle.net/ HTTP/1.1
Host: eu.battle.net
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.77 Safari/537.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.6
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3

Comment: GET http://eu.battle.net/en/ HTTP/1.1
Host: eu.battle.net
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.77 Safari/537.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.6
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: login.cookies=1

Comment: Basically what it does is jumping from us server to eu server. And there's no cookie setted up and I also removed all the history/cache/password/cookies from browser to make sure these things are not interrupting my investigation. Any other reason for the unexpected cookie?

Comment: I have navigated to battle.net and before I even attempted to log in battle.net had set 7 cookies: login.cookies, serviceBar.html5Warning, serviceBar.browserWarning, __utma, __utmb, __utmc, __utmz